# Given finite summation, find suitable function

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Which function(s) $f(x)$ fulfill the following condition:

$\sum_{i=0}^n f(i) = 1 + \frac{f(0)}{2}$

If an additional condition is necessary, then the function can be restricted to any decreasing monotonic function.

(If this is an existing homework question to any course, I'd be glad to know which course it is.)

Comment: What about the quantifier for $n$? For any $n$, or for some fixed value, say, $n=3$?

Comment: If it is to hold for all $n$ there is only one function that works (defined on the integers). Otherwise just pick any function $f$ you like and redefine $f(0)$ as to make the equality true.

Comment: Ideally for any prescribed $n>0$.  Maximum value < 100.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This property is way too weak if you're only speaking about one specific $n$. Given any fixed $n$, we must have
$$\sum_{i=0}^nf(i)=1+\frac12f(0)$$
which rewrites to
$$\sum_{i=1}^nf(i)=1-\frac12f(0)$$
Take *any* function, and set for example 
$$f(0)=2-2\sum_{i=1}^nf(i)$$
to make sure the property holds.

Even if we take into account that $f$ is a decreasing monotonic function (may I add, decreasing functions are always monotonic), there's still way too many functions to say anything useful about this.

---

**Edit:**
if we know $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ for some $a,b,c$, then we know with [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula)
that
$$\sum_{i=1}^nai^2+bi+c=a\frac{2n^3+3n^2+n}{6}+b\frac{n^2+n}{2}+cn$$
and since $1+\frac{1}{2}f(0)=1+\frac c2$, we must solve (for $a,b,c$)

$$a\frac{2n^3+3n^2+n}{6}+b\frac{n^2+n}{2}+cn=1-\frac c2$$
or
$$a\frac{2n^3+3n^2+n}{6}+b\frac{n^2+n}{2}+c(n+\frac 12)=1$$
and if $n$ is fixed, then we can simply choose two of $a,b,c$ and determine what the last one has to be - if however $a,b,c$ are fixed, then we can solve this equation (for it's only cubic in $n$) but, depending on $a,b,c$ of course, this most likely gives you non-natural $n$ and thus would not be possible.

Comment: Thank you very much.  If we restrict to $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, is it solvable for general, positive, prescribed integer n?

Comment: I edited my answer to adress $f(x)$ being a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: Very nice, dank je wel.  If we revert to a general, not necessarily quadratic $f(x)$, can a candidate family of functions be identified using only the following additional conditions? prescribed positive integer $n$, $f(0)>f(n)>0$, $\frac{df}{dx}>0$ everywhere on $0\le x \le n$.

Comment: Consider posting a new question rather than keep expanding on an existing question. Continuously changing your question is confusing to future readers and makes it harder for other people with similar questions to find the answer to their question.

Comment: Thank you.  First time user, yes I am.

Comment: Also, if I've answered your question, please consider marking it as "correct" to avoid answered questions filling up the "unanswered" section on this website.

Comment: Thanks for the help! http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2175118/identify-candidate-function-satisfying-finite-summation-and-additional-condition