# Identify candidate function satisfying finite summation and additional conditions.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Identify a candidate family of suitable f(x) which satisfy the following conditions:

1. prescribed positive integer $n$
2. $f(0)>f(n)>0$
3. $\frac{df}{dx}<0$ everywhere on $0\le x \le n$.
4. $\sum_{i=0}^n f(i) = 1+\frac{f(0)}{2}$

This is a follow-on question to the following: [Given finite summation, find suitable function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2174956/given-finite-summation-find-suitable-function#2174968)

(If this is an existing homework question to any course, I'd be glad to know which course it is.)

Comment: Do you only wish to find infinite functions satisfying the 4 conditions, or do you wish to find *all* functions satisfying the conditions? Also, note that you implicitly assume $f$ is differentiable on $[0,n]$ on condition (3)

Comment: Needn't be all imaginable functions satisfying the four conditions.  I do not understand the nuance between infinite functions and all functions.

Comment: I mean, are you satisfied having infinite solutions to your problem, or do you wish to find all solutions? Your phrasing "Identify a candidate family" confused me as to what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Infinite solutions would indeed be satisfactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define

$$H_n(\varepsilon)=\left(\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{(i+\varepsilon)^2}\right)-(1+\tfrac{1}{2\varepsilon^2})$$

Now, for integers $m>1$ (keep in mind, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}<1.7$):

\begin{align}
H_n(m)&=\left(\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{(i+m)^2}\right)-(1+\tfrac{1}{2m^2})\\
&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{(i+m)^2}\right)-1+\tfrac{1}{2m^2}\\
&<\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1-1+\tfrac{1}{2m^2}\\
&<1.7+\tfrac{1}{2m^2}-2\\
&<\tfrac{1}{2m^2}-0.3\\
&<0
\end{align}
and also
\begin{align}
H_n(\tfrac14)&=\left(\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{(i+\tfrac14)^2}\right)-(1+\tfrac{16}{2})\\
&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{(i+\tfrac14)^2}\right)+7\\
&>0
\end{align}

Note that $H_n$ is continuous and with the fact that $H_n(\tfrac14)>0$ and $H_n(m)<0$ for integers $m>1$, we know that (for each $n$) there must exist a $\alpha_n>\frac14$ such that $H_n(\alpha_n)=0$. Now set
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{(x+\alpha_n)^2}$$
We know $f(0)=\frac{1}{\alpha_n^2}>f(n)=\frac{1}{(\alpha_n+n)^2}$ (I state this even though the second condition is implied by the third). We also know $f$ is strictly decreasing on $(-\alpha_n,\infty]$, and thus on $[0,n]$. The fourth and last condition is satisfied since we picked $\alpha_n$ such that $$H_n(\alpha_n)\left(\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{(i+\alpha_n)^2}\right)-(1+\tfrac{1}{2\alpha_n^2})=0$$
which immediately implies
$$\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{(i+\alpha_n)^2}=1+\tfrac{1}{2\alpha_n^2}$$
which in terms of $f$ is
$$\sum_{i=0}^nf(i)=1+\tfrac{1}{2}f(0)$$
exactly as the fourth condition states. Thus, a family of functions satisfying given conditions would be $$f(x)=\frac{1}{(x+\alpha_n)^2}$$

Comment: Thank you very much.  The fact that we can chose any value for $\alpha_n>\frac{1}{4}$ means that there are infinite possibilities?  Must $\alpha_n=\alpha_{n+1}..$?

Comment: We can't choose any $\alpha_n>\tfrac14$, each $n$ has one $\alpha_n$ such that the function satisfies the conditions. And most likely $\alpha_n\neq\alpha_{n+1}$, but I didn't say anything about the separate $a_n$.

Comment: Got it.  thank you.  I'll mark as correct.